# OLS regression problem in R, where intercept is function of the other parameters

Tags: r, regression, least-squares, standard-error, lm

I'm having problems doing OLS in R using the `lm()` function on the following linear model:

$Y_t = \bar{Y} \cdot (1-a-b-c) + a \cdot X_{1t} + b \cdot X_{2t} + c \cdot X_{3t} + \varepsilon_{t}$

where $\bar{Y}$ is the sample mean. Moreover, the parameters need to satisfy the following constraints:
$a,b,c\geq 0$ and $a+b+c<1$ in order for $Y_t$ to be valid.

To be completely honest, I'm not sure this is even a linear regression problem, due to the inequality constraints. However, in the textbook I'm following, it is vaguely specified that the above problem can be estimated using OLS, however I'm open to other suggestions. Also, if you use another method, I would like to know how to acquire the standard errors from the estimation procedure. Feel free to cook up an example using random data.

Comment: This falls under the branch of "constrained optimization" and cannot be done using vanilla `lm()`, you will have to use another function.

Comment: I thought so. However, I'm unsure on how to do it using constrained optimization though.

Comment: This will require some manual work. Have a look at http://www.stat.ucla.edu/~handcock/combining/software/glmc.html

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look at it. I was also wondering how you estimate it, if we eliminated the constraints on the parameters? Then it should reduce to a problem that can be done using vanilla `lm()`.  In this case, I'm having trouble specifying the intercept parameter under the `lm()` function.